# curl error in a reactive expression from the googleAuthR package: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: r, shiny, google-compute-engine, reactive-programming, google-authentication

I am using googleAuthR, a R library that facilitates the use of Google APIs and Google OAuth, from a Shiny App hosted on a Google compute engine with Shiny Server.

When I trigger the OAuth authentication flow, I occasionnaly get an error right after the redirection to my app. No matter what I do after that, I cannot start a new Shiny session without getting the error (until I restart the server).

The logs say the following:

```
Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
  131: curl::curl_fetch_memory
  130: request_fetch.write_memory
  128: request_perform
  127: POST
  126: gar_shiny_getToken
  125: <reactive>
  109: accessToken
   96: shiny::renderUI
   95: func
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$gauth_login-googleAuthUi
    1: runApp
```

I've tried to update the R library and the problem still happens. I'm using googleAuthR 1.0.0.

My server.R code is quite simple, it's the googleAuthR typical use case.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

accessToken <- callModule(googleAuth, "gauth_login")

userDetails <- reactive({
   req(accessToken())
   with_shiny(get_user_info, shiny_access_token = accessToken())
 })

...

}
```

Same for the UI, I use the googleAuthR helper:

```
googleAuthUI("gauth_login")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi, the problem was eventually fixed, but many things were tried by many different people so it's unclear what fixed it unfortunately. Have you tried this:  sudo apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev ? Let me know if this works!

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Unfortunately, it did not work and all the possible workarounds I bumped into did not work either. I am waiting from a Google engineer and hopefully he can help.